# Control the frame size's animation to create a collapsable that always expands from top to bottom view in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, ios-animations

I'm trying to replicate an accordion component that should work like the one in the **Custom Control Label** from [this](https://mantine.dev/core/accordion/) documentation. To do this I created a Collapsable view as follows:

```
struct Collapsable<Content>: View where Content: View {
    internal var content: () -> Content
    @Binding private var isCollapsed: Bool
    @State private var isCollapsedForAnimation: Bool 
    
    init(isCollapsed: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._isCollapsed = isCollapsed
        self.content = content
        self.isCollapsedForAnimation = isCollapsed.wrappedValue
    }

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            .frame(maxHeight: isCollapsedForAnimation ? 0 : nil, alignment: .top)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .clipped()
            .onChange(of: self.isCollapsed) { isCollapsed in
                withAnimation {
                    self.isCollapsedForAnimation = isCollapsed
                }    
            }
        }
}
```

And it works as in it allows me to show and hide the content of the `content` parameter, but the animation is terribly inconsistent, since they way it expands/contracts depends on the container. I would like the view to always expand and contract from bottom to top, or even better, allow the user to specify whether he wants it to animate from top to bottom or the other way around.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get this behavior, so I'm looking for hints in the right direction.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code of a container where it doesn't work the way you want it to? At first glance, my gut would've said that your `frame(alignment: .top)` should make it behave consistently.

Comment: @BrockBatsell: If I embed this view inside a `VStack` with `frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)` the `Collapsable` (say it contains two `Text` element just for the sake of the example) shrinks toward its central alignment guide.

Comment: You likely have to go into UIKit for this so you can set the anchor point.

Comment: Have you tried using a ```DisclosureGroup```?

Comment: @BenzyNeez: I already checked out`DisclosureGroup` and for some reason I had the impression that you couldn't customize the label, which appears to be false. I'll let you know if it worked as soon as I turn on my macbook

Comment: @loremipsum: That's what I'm trying to avoid if possible. I know that sooner or later I would regret.

Comment: There is no reason to avoid UIKit. It is quite necessary for the foreseeable future if you want to have custom UI.

Comment: @loremipsum: One of the reasons I'd like to avoid is that I started developing software for iOS using SwiftUI and I have little familiarity with layout (especially constraint) in UIKit. It would take potentially a lot (hopefully not but you never know) of time for such an apparently simple task

Comment: SwiftUI is a good way to start but it is a “one size fits many” style of coding if you want “tailor made” you have to go deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that **you must test on a real device**, not on the simulator. The iOS simulator often has display bugs that real devices don't.

The second thing to understand is that SwiftUI animations can be flaky and difficult even on devices.

Anyway, let's reproduce the accordion component you linked to, in SwiftUI. Here's my result:

[image: An animated GIF showing a stack of three name cards. The top card is for Bender. The middle card is for Mom. The bottom card is for Homer. I tap each card in turn to expand it so that it shows more info. When a card expands, any other expanded card collapses at the same time.]

I recorded this on my iPhone 12 Mini running iOS 16.4. On the device it looks much smoother, but I generated the animated GIF at 15 fps to get it down to an almost reasonable file size.

Anyway, here's my implementation of `CustomControlLabel`:

```
struct CustomControlLabel<Header: View, Content: View>: View {
    @Binding
    var isExpanded: Bool
    let header: Header
    let content: Content

    init(
        isExpanded: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder header: () -> Header,
        @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content
    ) {
        _isExpanded = isExpanded
        self.header = header()
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                header
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .font(.caption2)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 180 : 0))
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture { isExpanded.toggle() }
            content
                .opacity(isExpanded ? 1 : 0)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .padding(.top, 16)
                .frame(height: isExpanded ? nil : 0, alignment: .top)
                .clipped()
        }
        .padding()
        .padding(1)
        .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
        .background {
            if isExpanded {
                Color.black.opacity(0.05)
            }
        }
        .padding(-0.5)
    }
}
```

Here are two key differences between my code and yours:

1. I use the `fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` modifier on the collapsing content, inside the `frame` modifier that sets its height to zero when it's collapsed. This `fixedSize` modifier hides the zero height from the content, so it doesn't try to change its own layout to fit in a zero height.
2. I don't perform the animation at this level. Expanding one `CustomControlLabel` should simultaneously collapse any other expanded `CustomControlLabel`. To get the overall layout to animate correctly, I apply an `animation` modifier to the container that contains all of the `CustomControlLabel`s.

It's also important that the `VStack` in there has `spacing: 0`. The default is that SwiftUI picks a spacing it thinks is appropriate, but that spacing changes when the content is entirely collapsed! So without the `spacing: 0`, the collapsible content moves slightly as its visibility changes. To prevent that, I set `spacing: 0` and added `padding(.top, 16)` to the collapsible content.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
struct ToonHeader: View {
    let pic: UIImage
    let name: String
    let blurb: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(uiImage: pic)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(name)
                Text(blurb)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}

enum Selection: Equatable {
    case bender
    case mom
    case homer
}

struct CustomControlLabelTestView: View {
    @State
    var selection: Selection? = nil

    func binding(for target: Selection) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return .init(
            get: { selection == target },
            set: {
                if $0 {
                    selection = target
                } else if selection == target {
                    selection = nil
                }
            }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            CustomControlLabel(isExpanded: binding(for: .bender)) {
                ToonHeader(
                    pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "futurama-bender.png"),
                    name: "Bender Bending Rodríguez",
                    blurb: "Fascinated with cooking, though has no sense of taste"
                )
            } content: {
                Text("Bender Bending Rodríguez (born September 4, 2996), designated Bending Unit 22, and commonly known as Bender, is a bending unit created by a division of MomCorp in Tijuana, Mexico, and his serial number is 2716057. His mugshot id number is 01473. He is Fry's best friend.")
                    .font(.caption)
            }

            CustomControlLabel(isExpanded: binding(for: .mom)) {
                ToonHeader(
                    pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "futurama-mom.png"),
                    name: "Carol Miller",
                    blurb: "One of the richest people on Earth"
                )
            } content: {
                Text("Carol Miller (born January 30, 2880), better known as Mom, is the evil chief executive officer and shareholder of 99.7% of Momcorp, one of the largest industrial conglomerates in the universe and the source of most of Earth's robots. She is also one of the main antagonists of the Futurama series.")
                    .font(.caption)
            }

            CustomControlLabel(isExpanded: binding(for: .homer)) {
                ToonHeader(
                    pic: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "homer-simpson.png"),
                    name: "Homer Simpson",
                    blurb: "Overweight, lazy, and often ignorant"
                )
            } content: {
                Text("Homer Jay Simpson (born May 12) is the main protagonist and one of the five main characters of The Simpsons series(or show). He is the spouse of Marge Simpson and father of Bart, Lisa and Maggie Simpson.")
                    .font(.caption)
            }

            Spacer()
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1/6), value: selection)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

You'll need to scroll down but at the bottom you'll find the single `animation` modifier that animates everything.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so one of the issues is that, mid-animation, the implicit `VStack` is offering all of its content equally-decreasing sizes, which causes each `Text` view to reduce its line count / truncation behavior. There are a number of ways you could fix that — the easiest one I can think of is to make the implicit wrapping `VStack` explicit, then tell the inner content that its vertical size should remain fixed.

```swift
VStack {
    content()
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    .frame(maxHeight: isCollapsedForAnimation ? 0 : nil, alignment: .top)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .clipped()
    .onChange(of: self.isCollapsed) { isCollapsed in
        withAnimation {
            self.isCollapsedForAnimation = isCollapsed
        }
    }
```

Depending on the complexity of your views, this may or may not cause issues. If it does, then I think I would move toward always providing a single concrete `View` to `Collapsible` whose geometry does not depend on the automatic layout that `V/HStack` will provide.

Comment: I tried your solution, tested with this code: https://pastebin.com/NQfEUX8m . Unfortunately the collapse animation still depends on external factors, for instance if I place the `Collapsable` between two `Spacer()`s the animation still happens toward the center alignment guide. Or if I place a single `Spacer()` before and none after, the animation happens from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: styling updated to resemble the Custom Control Label in your example more closely. You could make the label more elaborate if you needed to.*

I was asking if you had tried using a `DisclosureGroup`. I've found that in fact its content does not get revealed or hidden very smoothly and the label can also be seen to blink when tapped. Maybe there are ways of resolving these issues. However, it is possible to emulate this component and achieve a smooth animation simply by using the default transition for content being revealed in a `VStack`, as shown below.

The content that is below the hidden section slides down nicely to make space, the content that is being revealed is shown with an opacity transition by default. This all works quite smoothly without much extra effort.

```swift
struct AccordionSection<Content : View>: View {
    private let label: LocalizedStringKey
    private let content: () -> Content
    @Binding private var isExpanded: Bool

    init(
        _ label: LocalizedStringKey,
        isExpanded: Binding<Bool>,
        content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.label = label
        self._isExpanded = isExpanded
        self.content = content
    }

    private var accordionButton: some View {
        Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isExpanded ? 360 : 180))
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(label)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .overlay(alignment: .trailing) { accordionButton }
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
            if isExpanded {
                content()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(isExpanded
                    ? Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
                    : Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
        )
        .clipped()
        .overlay(
            Rectangle().stroke()
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isExpanded = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Text("Content above Accordion section").italic()
            AccordionSection(
                "Lorem ipsum",
                isExpanded: $isExpanded
            ) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                    Text("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
                    Text("Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.")
                    Text("Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
                }
                .padding(.top, 20)
            }
            Text("Content below Accordion section").italic()
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, 100)
    }
}
```